# How do I add an integer to a string using Console.WriteLine?

Tags: c#, string, integer

I'm currently writing a program in C# and I'm practicing using integers. I'm trying to make it so the written line comes out with the int at the end. It doesn't give me the outcome I want though, and when I searched on Google it didn't give me the solution I was looking for.

Code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int Pi = rnd.Next(1,5); 

Console.WriteLine("Checking 'Pi' value...");
Console.Beep(37,1000);
Console.WriteLine("Pi value found. Pi = ",Pi);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Outcome:

```
Checking 'Pi' value...
Pi value found. Pi =
```

If you know anything I can try, please let me know.

Comment: you can also do `WriteLine($"pi = {Pi} today")` this is called 'string interpolation'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **many** ways to do this:

```
// placeholder
Console.WriteLine("Pi value found. Pi = {0}",Pi);

// concatenation
Console.WriteLine("Pi value found. Pi = " + Pi.ToString());

// interpolation
Console.WriteLine($"Pi value found. Pi = {Pi}");

// StringBuilder
var sb = new StringBuilder("Pi value found. Pi = ").Append(Pi);
Console.WriteLine(sb);

// multiple writes
Console.Write("Pi value found. Pi = ");
Console.WriteLine(Pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Pi Value found. Pi =" + Pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

1. `Console.WriteLine("Pi Value found. Pi = " + Pi);`, which is a shortened version of `Console.WriteLine("Pi Value found. Pi = " + Pi.ToString());`.

This works because operators like + do different things depending on what you use them on. C# automatically adds `ToString()` to your integer, converting it to, well, a string. This means what you're actually passing into `Console.WriteLine` now looks like this (assuming your random number generation generated the number 4 in this case: `"Pi Value found. Pi = " + "4"`. Notice the quotation marks around the 4 - you now simply have two strings. For two strings, the "+"-Operator concatenates them, creating the single string `"Pi Value found. Pi = 4"` in this case.

2. `Console.WriteLine($"Pi Value found. Pi = {Pi}")` or `Console.WriteLine("Pi Value found. Pi = {0}", Pi)` (although not quite the same technically, they're different ways of writing essentially the same thing for your purposes)

This is string interpolation. Essentially what you're doing with this is defining a template to format the string by - done either directly by the compiler, which is the $-method of doing it ([see here for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)), or by providing a template that Console.WriteLine passes into String.Format for you.

It doesn't really matter which of these you choose, they are all valid ways of achieving the same goal.